# Deleting an item from a list in React updates the state, but component doesn't re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When deleting from a list in React the item successfully is deleted from the `tags` state, but the `Tag` doesn't update? I fixed this by using `{ props.name }` in the place of `{ name }` in `Tag.js` but I don't understand why that change is necessary. Doesn't React re-render the `Tag`s automatically?

Thanks!!

```js
//TagManager.js component

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Tag from './Tag.js';

export default function TagManager() {
    let [tags, setTags] = useState(["one", "two", "three", "four"]);
    function deleteTag(tagToDelete) {
        let filteredTags = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < tags.length; index = index + 1) {
            if (tags[index] !== tagToDelete) {
                filteredTags.push(tags[index]);
            }
        }
        setTags(filteredTags);
    }
    function renderTags() {
        let tagsToRender = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < tags.length; index = index + 1) {
            tagsToRender.push(<Tag key = { index } name = { tags[index] } handleClick = { deleteTag }/>);
        }
        return tagsToRender;
    }
    return (
    <div className = "tag-manager">
        { renderTags() }
    </div>
    )
}

///////////////////////////////////
//Tag.js component

import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default function Tag(props) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(props.name)
    return (
    <div className = "tag" id = {props.id} onClick = {() => props.handleClick(props.name)} >{ name }</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: the problem is that array index should not be used as key

Comment: Yeah that's how I fixed it, but I guess what I'm asking is why? Why does it not work as expected when I use an index as a key?

Comment: you can find information here https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: and for a more extended response https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children

Comment: Alright, I've almost got it. But I'm trying to understand it via example. Say I delete item "two" then I'll see the tags "one", "two", "three" on the screen. Could you step me through how it ends up like that? Thanks!

Comment: @AngelSalazar If you could I'd super appreciate the help. I'm pretty new to React :(

Comment: Still never figured this out :(